# OrderBy in PXProjection Select does not work

Tags: acumatica

Have any of you experienced this issue in Acumatica?
Adding OrderBy to Select2 in PXProjection attribute has no effect.
I checked the SQL query in Request Profiler and the data is sorted by key fields of the DAC.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your OrderBy to the PXSelect which is using the DAC made with the PXProjection. Note that by default, the records are ordered by the DAC keys.

Answer (score 0):

In almost every case Acumatica will sort by the key fields first, so if your expectation was to have the data sorted exactly as in your OrderBy<> criteria then this won't work. What you can do instead of override the order directly in the view delegate, like this:

```
PXView select = new PXView(Base, true, this.myView.View.BqlSelect);
select.OrderByNew<OrderBy<Desc<MyDac.myField1, Desc<MyDac.myField2>>>>();
//<rest logic to select from the view>
```

This will *always* replace the order with your custom sort order. If you only want to do it only when the user hasn't altered the sort order in a grid, you can add a condition like that:

```
if (PXView.SortColumns.Length == this.myView.Cache.Keys.Length)
{
    // apply custom default sort order
    select.OrderByNew<OrderBy<Desc<MyDac.myField1, Desc<MyDac.myField2>>>>();
}
```